If LGPL 2.1 source code is in my project. Does the whole project need to be LGPL? Or just the class that call it?
I'm relatively new to library licenses and come from a game development background.
I'm developing an open-source game development tool that directly includes the source code of an LGPL 2.1 library.
However, only one script in the project depends on the LGPL 2.1 library. The other scripts do not use or rely on it at all.
My questions are:

Do I have to license the entire project under LGPL 2.1, or just the part that directly references and uses it (e.g., a class that calls a function from it)? Ideally, I'd like to keep the rest of the project licensed under MIT.

If I want to publish the project on GitHub, what license should I display at the root of the project? a MIT license / LGPL / mixed?

This might be a silly question, but games made from this tool as a closed-source commercial product don't have to comply with LGPL 2.1 in anyway right?



When you say "directly includes", does this mean that the user no longer will see a .dll file of the LGPL library when she uses your end program? Normally a LGPL library is delivered alongside the program as a .dll or .so file, or something equivalent, in order to comply. That's not the only way to comply, of course, but it's the most common way.

@Brandin Thank you, I think I'll just go ahead and package it as a seperate .dll file.

As usual, the devil is in the details and in this case if your tool is a modification of the library or a usage of the library.

If you have copied the library code into your project folders primarily for convenience and you have not made any changes to that code, then your tool is just a user of the library and you only have to comply with a small part of the LGPL2.1 license. In essence, your tool can have any license you like, but you must give the recipients of the tool the right and ability to replace the LGPL library with a different version.
This case is easiest shown in your repository if the library has a sub-folder of its own that contains everything, including license files and readme's. Then you can just mention the license of your own code at the root of your repository and maybe mention the use/existence of the LGPL library in a readme file.

If you have take portions of the library and built (some of) your tools out of them, then your code is a modification of the library and the full LGPLv2.1 license applies to you. This means that you must license your code also under the LGPLv2.1 license.
If you can make a plausible case that the scripts in your toolbox are independent works as far as copyright is concerned, then you could license them each individually and only the one that is actually based on the library then needs to be under the LGPL license. But you will have to maintain that separation and make sure no code gets shared between the scripts.



Regarding your third question, this depends entirely on the relation between the game and the LGPL code.
If any LGPL code ends up in the game as a separate library, then the people that have a copy of the game must have the right to replace that LGPL library. If any LGPL code ends up in the game in another way, then the game itself must be distributed under the LGPL license.
If only the output of your tools ends up in the game itself, then the license of your tools does not affect in any way the license choices for the game itself.

Thank you! Regarding the last question, If I managed to package the LGPL library as a .dll file ( dynamic linking ). How do I let the user modify or replace them if my game is a commercial product that should not be hacked into? Do I have to delibalately make the interface or instruction that user can follow to replace or remove LGPL library from the game file? Or does making it a .dll  enough?

@PhunPeeticharoenthum the expectation is that the user who wants to replace the LGPL code has enough programming knowledge to replace a dll with one they built themselves.
